Permanent residency for a disabled person from Pakistan
I am a 42 years old but unfortunatly a disabled person from Pakistan. I have an MBA in Finance and am curently working in education department. As my dependents I have a wife and three children. My wife is also well educated and working in education department.
I want to migrate to Japan. How would I go about it?

Start by researching eg https://www.expatica.com/jp/move/immigration/japan-visa-79399/. Do you speak Japanese?

There are a few ways that you could legally migrate to Japan, with possibility of permanent residency:

By establishing or acquiring a business in Japan, or by serving on the board of directors of such a business. This will qualify you for a "Business Manager" or "Highly Skilled Professional" (if qualified) visa.

By finding employment in Japan. This will qualify you for either a "Technology/Humanities/International Affairs" visa or a "Highly Skilled Professional" visa (again, if you qualify).

By finding a job in your home country and being transferred by your employer to Japan. This will qualify you for a "Internal Transfer" visa.


Generally you will need to maintain residence for 10 years to become a permanent resident, though highly skilled professionals can obtain PR in as short as 1 year. Most other visas will not provide a path to permanent residency. Disabled persons are not disqualified or otherwise discriminated in this process, provided you fulfill all other requirements.
